# How to change default zoom settings for entire website in Shopify?

Tags: shopify, zooming

So basically I want to adjust my Shopify theme so that it's zoomed out a bit. From the normal view of 100%, I'd like it to be what it looks like at 75% zoom (when zoomed in on a browser).

What do i need to do to achieve this?

Comment: Do you just want to test it locally, or do you want the whole site to actually be smaller? If the former, you can open up the dev tools on your browser and switch to mobile preview/responsive mode; if the latter, you could try [CSS Zoom](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-zoom), which is non-standard but appears to work on most browsers

Comment: Hi Davel,
yes, I actually want to scale down the site, the site is too much in the face.
Ok, I wiil try the css zoom way, will let you know.

Comment: Ah! No worries - the zoom rule would go in as a CSS rule in one of your theme's `.css` or `.scss` files, which are all found in your theme's `assets` folder.  For example, if your theme has a file called `theme.scss`, you could add `body{ zoom: 75%;  }` to test to see if this works for you